# Socket accepting only one client

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, server

I have created a server in java which accepts client connections. But I am able to only connect one client

```
class Server extends Thread{

    private void startServer() {

     try{
        ss=new ServerSocket(3000);
        s=ss.accept();
        DataRead d1=new DataRead();        
        d1.t.start();



         }catch(Exception er){
             er.printStackTrace();
         }
        }                                        
  }
```

Comment: please ignore the Conn class., i forgot to remove it from the server code

Comment: You need to do more debugging first. 1. Does it work in the same process, same machine etc. 2. you need to check that data is sent in the correct format and also received in the correct manner. A TCP dump tool like wireshark may be able to help you. Once you've determined where the error is - come back on here aad ask in detail with the results. All in all the challenge is for you to first determine where the error is - then people can help you isolate a fix.

Comment: the problem basically is, when i am running the server, and run a client on the same machine it is doing what the program is expected to do i.e all messages are displayed in server as well as client (echo) but when i run another instance of client, it gets connected but no messages are diaplayed on sever and there is no echo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only ever accept one socket. In your `jButton1ActionPerformed` you have

```
s=ss.accept();
```

But that is only invoked **once**, when you click the jButton1 button. You need to keep calling `accept()` to if you want to have multiple clients able to connect.

Also, keep in mind that each call to `accept()` will block until a client connects and then return a **new** socket, representing that connection. So if you want to support multiple client, you shouldn't have your `Socket` as a global variable, it should instead be included in the constructor of your `DataRead` class, so each reader operates on a unique socket/connection/client.

Comment: actually i was thinking to make two threads, one for accepting connections and other for i/o from server. is that possible?

Comment: Good luck! You'll probably want to start a separate thread that handles the server-socket (calls `accept()`)